# Select first name per sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
-- set up test table
Declare @TEST TABLE(Name VarChar(100), Sequence VarChar(500))

-- insert test data
INSERT INTO @TEST (Name,Sequence) SELECT 'A_01' , 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'
INSERT INTO @TEST (Name,Sequence) SELECT 'A_02' , 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'
INSERT INTO @TEST (Name,Sequence) SELECT 'A_03' , 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'
INSERT INTO @TEST (Name,Sequence) SELECT 'A_04' , 'TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT'
INSERT INTO @TEST (Name,Sequence) SELECT 'A_05' , 'TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT'
INSERT INTO @TEST (Name,Sequence) SELECT 'A_06' , 'GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG'
INSERT INTO @TEST (Name,Sequence) SELECT 'A_07' , 'CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC'

-- select test data
SELECT Name, Sequence FROM @TEST ORDER BY Name, Sequence
```

Results:

```
 Name                           Sequence
 A_01                    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
 A_02                    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
 A_03                    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
 A_04                    TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
 A_05                    TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
 A_06                    GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
 A_07                    CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
```

How can I write a query to remove rows with duplicated `Sequence` values, while still retaining the first `Name` that comes with the `Sequence`?

```
 Name                           Sequence
 A_01                    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
 A_04                    TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
 A_06                    GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
 A_07                    CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
```

Comment: Have you tried using the DISTINCT keyword?

Comment: did you tried `distinct`? something like `select distinct...`

Comment: distinct is remove 100% duplicate row but this is remaining only one row which is different Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT *,
                ROW_NUMBER()
                  OVER (PARTITION BY Sequence
                            ORDER BY NAME) AS RN
         FROM   @TEST)
SELECT NAME,
       Sequence
FROM   T
WHERE  RN = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`SELECT DISTINCT Name, Sequence FROM @TEST ORDER BY Name, Sequence`